# C# generics not recognizing type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I can't figure out why the following code returns a `Cannot resolve method Write(T)` - it seems unambiguous to me:

> ```
>     private static void WriteToDisk<T>(string fileName, T[] vector)
>     {
>         using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
>         {
>             using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
>             {
>                foreach(T v in vector) writer.Write(v);
>                 writer.Close();
>             }
>         }
>     }
> ```

I would like to define a generic binary write method that can deal with vectors of, e.g., `int[]`, `long[]` or `double[]`.

Comment: Side note: you don't need to close writer, since you are disposing it anyway.

Comment: "it seems unambiguous to me"? Really?  Which overload will it choose if you pass in an array of objects?

Comment: `BinaryWriter.Write()` does not accept objects as an argument. The compiler can know in advance all types with which the method will be called, and could pre-compile a series of implementations of the method template. Is this available in C#?

Comment: @ZeJibe No, that feature does not exist. Generics are not templates: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/07/30/generics-are-not-templates.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

cdhowie has the correct explanation. Overload resolution happens at compile-time, and in this case nothing is known about `T`, so no overload is applicable.

With `dynamic`, overload resolution happens runtime. Maybe you can use:

```
writer.Write((dynamic)v)
```

It will be a bit slow because of boxing and repeated overload resolution taking place runtime.

**Edit:** If for some reason you don't have access to `dynamic`, you can get a similar behavior with explicit reflection:

```
private static void WriteToDisk<T>(string fileName, T[] vector)
{
    var correctMethod = typeof(BinaryWriter).GetMethod("Write", new[] { typeof(T), });
    if (correctMethod == null)
        throw new ArgumentException("No suitable overload found for type " + typeof(T), "T");
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
           foreach(var v in vector)
               correctMethod.Invoke(writer, new object[] { v, });
        }
    }
}
```

I don't know if this is faster or slower than `dynamic`.

In either case, if you accidentally use a type `T` (such as `DateTime`) which is not supported by `BinaryWriter`, everything will compile fine, and you will only discover your mistake at runtime (when the code runs). See jam40jeff's answer for a more type-safe solution where you specify the overload yourself by passing in a delegate instance to the method.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jeppe - it works indeed. After a quick performance benchmark, `dynamic` is twice as slow as with explicit types (but you only need to write code once for all types!). Isn't there a way to tell the compiler to automatically generate the same method but for all possible types that will be used by the program (and that should be known at compile time?) A sort of macro maybe?

Comment: @ZeJibe I added some more info to my answer, for completeness.

Comment: @ZeJibe It's impossible to know "all possible types" that may be used with your method at compile-time. The type system is open-ended. Even if your method is assembly-internal (and therefore you can theoretically prove which types might be used at compile-time) there is always the possibility of invoking your method with reflection and giving it an object of some type that the compiler didn't account for.

Comment: @cdhowie Great point - yet they have it in C++. Templates are particularly useful when you have to deal with, e.g., large data files where column types are not known in advance. In C++ you end up writing one templated method; unfortunately, in C# you have to write a method for each data type or go for generics/dynamics as discussed here (but then you lose performance which is hardly acceptable with large data sets). Shall we lobby Microsoft to include some kind of clever templating into C#?

Comment: @ZeJibe In C++, template instantiations are compiled at compile-time, by the C++ compiler. In C#, generic class instantiations are compiled by the runtime and/or AOT, *not* by the C# compiler.  By the time that the runtime sees the generic class definition, *all method calls have already been resolved by the C# compiler.*  Implementing templates in C# means that the *source code* for the template class (or some new byte-code format) must be present in the assembly, otherwise things like overloaded operators could not be resolved when the template was instantiated.

Answer (score 10):

Which overload of `Write()` to call will be determined at compile time, not at runtime.  `BinaryWriter` would need a `Write(object)` overload (or a `Write<T>(T)` generic overload) to allow calling the method this way.  This error (correctly) indicates that it has neither.

You will need to write your own wrapper method that accepts an `object` (or a generically-typed argument) and inspects its type to determine which `BinaryWriter.Write()` overload to call.

Comment: More than that: it will be determined while processing the generic definition, not when the generic is used (and `T` is known).

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22088/discussion-between-cdhowie-and-ben-voigt)

Answer (score 3):

I disagree that `dynamic` is the best way to go.  The problem here is that you need to guarantee that callers pass a type `T` that `BinaryWriter.Write()` can handle.  Since there is no common class or interface that can guarantee this by constraining `T`, the best way to do that is to "pass the buck" to the caller as follows:

```
private static void WriteToDisk<T>(string fileName, T[] vector, Action<BinaryWriter, T> callWrite)
{
    using (var stream = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
    {
        using (var writer = new BinaryWriter(stream))
        {
            foreach (T v in vector)
                callWrite(writer, v);
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

This is called as follows:

```
WriteToDisk("filename", new int[0], (w, o) => w.Write(o)); // compiles
WriteToDisk("filename", new string[0], (w, o) => w.Write(o)); // compiles
WriteToDisk("filename", new DateTime[0], (w, o) => w.Write(o)); // doesn't compile (as desired)
```

Of course, if there's only a small set of known types, you can create "convenience methods" as such:

```
private static void WriteToDisk(string fileName, int[] vector)
{
    WriteToDisk(fileName, vector, (w, o) => w.Write(o));
}

private static void WriteToDisk(string fileName, string[] vector)
{
    WriteToDisk(fileName, vector, (w, o) => w.Write(o));
}
```

and now your calls are simply:

```
WriteToDisk("filename", new int[0]);
WriteToDisk("filename", new string[0]);
```

A little more code, but a lot more compile-time type safety and speed.

Answer (score 0):

You can change it to:

```
private static void WriteToDisk<T>(string fileName, T[] vector) where T : struct, IComparable,IComparable<T>
```

if you want to keep type of array as number value type.

Comment: Good idea, but not enough to make things compile. Are you sure about the _order_ of the constraints?

Comment: @fex To expand on what BenVoigt said, there is no `Write()` overload that accepts `IComparable` nor `IComparable<T>`, so this technique won't really help at all.